# Zuul does not work on weblogic- 12.2.1.2.0

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have some microservices that are backed behind zuul netflix that is run with tomcat 8(with java -jar command).
My context root of api-gateway into application.yml is `/` and context root of any microservice is `/app`.

The config of rout of api-gateway is like this:

```
zuul:
  host:
      connect-timeout-millis: 10000
      socket-timeout-millis: 60000

  routes:
#Micro1  
    micro1:
      path: /app/micro1/**
      sensitiveHeaders:
      url: http://192.168.251.141:3080/app/micro1
.
.
.
```

Everything is right when It is run with tomcat8 but unfortunately I am not able to run it into weblogic-12.1.3.
The weblogic.xml under webapp/WEB_INF directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd
                                        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
                                        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:context-root>/</wls:context-root>
    <wls:charset-params>
        <wls:input-charset>
            <wls:resource-path>/*</wls:resource-path>
            <wls:java-charset-name>UTF-8</wls:java-charset-name>
        </wls:input-charset>
    </wls:charset-params>

    <wls:jsp-descriptor>
        <wls:page-check-seconds>8</wls:page-check-seconds>
    </wls:jsp-descriptor>

    <wls:fast-swap>
        <wls:enabled>false</wls:enabled>
        <wls:refresh-interval>8</wls:refresh-interval>
    </wls:fast-swap>

    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javassist.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>

</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

I have searched on google but I have not found suitable result.
Where is the problem?
Is there an specific configuration that I do not config it in weblogic-12.1.3.
thanks for your answer.

PART 2:
Is it true that api-gateway as one microservice that is an small application is run by great application server such as weblogic?

Comment: "I am not able to run it into weblogic" - what happens?

Comment: There are not anything in the log file.I do not know.

Comment: How do I see what happens

Comment: If it is not running in weblogic, have you started the deployment?

Comment: Zuul is starter successfully on weblogic but when request is sended to it not rout the request.I put logback in the classes to see the log for detecting the problem but Nothing log is seen in the log file.